Button with popover wrapped in control not working inside menu
I've created control which wraps button and popover. Here is the code:
struct PopoverButton<DestinationView: View>: View {
    let label: LocalizedStringKey
    let image: String
    let destinationView: DestinationView
        
    @State private var isVisible = false
        
    init(label: LocalizedStringKey, image: String, @ViewBuilder _ destinationView: () -> DestinationView) {
        self.label = label
        self.image = image
        self.destinationView = destinationView()
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            isVisible = true
        }, label: {
            Label(label, systemImage: image)
        })
        .popover(isPresented: $isVisible, content: {
            destinationView
        })
    }
}

In general it works, but there is an issue when control is placed inside Menu:
.toolbar {
    ToolbarItem(placement: .automatic) {
        PopoverButton(label: "working", image: "pencil") {
            WorkingView()
        }
    }
    ToolbarItem(placement: .automatic) {
        Menu {
            PopoverButton(label: "not.working", image: "arrow.down.right") {
                NotWorkingView()
            }
        } label: {
            Image(systemName: "plus")
        }
        
    }
}

In this case first PopoverButton is working, second one placed in menu is displaying, but not showing popover. Flag is set to true, but popover callback is not fired.
Any suggestions?

Well yeah, built-in menus just cannot present popovers. What is the desired result here? Where should the popover pop from? Perhaps you want a submenu instead?

Ok, that might have sense :) I was testing this on phone so it was actually displayed as a sheet and I forgot about iPad. Good catch
